# HTML - Attribute autocomplete="on" not working in Chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome

I added `autocomplete="on"` in input tag:

```
<input autocomplete="on" type="email">
```

It's working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to give `field-name` for the `autocomplete` attribute:

```
<input autocomplete="email" type="email" />
```

Chrome has some settings related to it, which you might need to enable.

[image]

Moreover, for some reason, it looks like Chrome doesn't allow `autocomplete="on"` or `autocomplete="field-name"`, because it is a security decision by Google, so there are a few extensions that have been made to support it:

- [Autocomplete On](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/gdhbgagnmhdafendedikgjimegoipbnk?hl=en)
- [Source code of Chrome Extension to turn Autocomplete On](https://github.com/kzahel/autocomplete_on)

A gist of the source is:

```
// Code design inspired by http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/7347 .  Not
// overriding form submit prototypes like that does because I don't know of a
// good way to do this with Isolated Worlds (see http://groups.google.com/
// group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/118689ceda861163/ff25578ed3585edd )
// and I'm not sure the password manager would pick it up anyway (see comment
// below).

function enableAutocomplete()
{
    var snapshot = document.evaluate('//@autocomplete',
        document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null),
        numItems = snapshot.snapshotLength - 1;

    for (var i = numItems; i >= 0; i--)
        snapshot.snapshotItem(i).nodeValue = 'on';
}

// The password manager code checks for "autocomplete=off" in a callback
// from WebCore when the DOM content is loaded.  It doesn't seem to be
// documented, but this callback seems to happen after in-page event listeners
// fire, and before content scripts with "run_at" = "document_end" are loaded.
// Therefore, we load this script early and then run the actual transform code
// on an appropriate event listener.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', enableAutocomplete, false);
```

The above documented code will enable you to use `autocomplete` as usual.

For more information, please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autocomplete).

Comment: I tried with <input autocomplete="email" type="email" /> not working, Password & Forms I checked Enable Autofill -- Not working for me